# Is it possible to start/configure the confluent docker images with a property file instead of environment variables?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

[The docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/configuration.html) state that the cp-zookeeper and cp-kafka images are configured via environment variables.

> The ZooKeeper image uses variables prefixed with ZOOKEEPER_ with the variables expressed exactly as they would appear in the zookeeper.properties file. As an example, to set clientPort, tickTime, and syncLimit run the command below:

```
 docker run -d \
--net=host \
--name=zookeeper \
-e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 \
-e ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000 \
-e ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT=2
confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:3.3.1
```

I would prefer to provide a `zookeeper.properties` (server.properties for kafka) instead of specifying the ZOOKEEPER_* (KAFKA_*) environment variables. Is this somehow possible?

In my current setup with "non-confluent" kafka I simply mount a config volume containing the properties on /etc/kafka and then start kafka with that, but looking at the [confluent docker images](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images) I can see that this won't work since there's some special templating-magic going on in order to generate the properties inside the container.

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve what you describe by using the `--env-file` switch with your docker command instead of typing every environment variable in the command line.

For example, if you first store your desired properties to a file, let's say `kafka.properties`:

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:32181
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
```

then you may start your kafka container by running:

`docker run -d --net=host --name=kafka --env-file ./kafka.properties confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.3.1`

Still, the names of the property keys should match what each docker image is expecting (which as you noticed are rendered to the respective service properties when each docker image runs).